# How to insert today's date into a IMAGE URL?

Tags: javascript

I have a question that has been resolved here:
[How to insert today's date into a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728219/how-to-insert-todays-date-into-a-url)

Now I have other problem.
I have the image URL as follows:

```
http://cache3-img1.pressdisplay.com/pressdisplay/docserver/getimage.aspx?file=61072015010500000000001001&page=1&scale=44
```

and I input to HTML page as follows:

```
<img src="http://cache3-img1.pressdisplay.com/pressdisplay/docserver/getimage.aspx?file=61072015010500000000001001&page=1&scale=44" width="150"/>
```

...20150105... numbers in the URL is today's date .

How do I insert today's date code on the IMAGE URL using javascript like my previous problem .

Comment: Do you know the entire layout of the `file=...` part? What is the pattern here?

Comment: Only the date 20150105, while the " file = ... " is part of the overall IMAGE URL.

Comment: Is it **always** `file=6107<8-digit date>00000000001001`?

Comment: What is that 6107 part that precedes the date and do you know if that part will always be 4 digits long?

Comment: To PM 77-1, that's right. 6107 is code for image of The Jakarta Post epaper

Answer (score 2):

To set an image source, first you get a reference to it, imagine it has an ID of dateImage:

```
<img id="dateImage">
```

You can get it with jQuery like so:

```
var img = $("#dateImage");
```

Then to get the date string, which I believe you have as yyyymmdd, you could do it like so:

```
var now = new Date();
var month = now.getMonth()+1;
if(month < 10) month = "0" + month;
var day = now.getDate();
if(day < 10) day = "0" + day;
var dateStr = now.getFullYear() + month + day;
```

This gives you a string like 20140109. You have other stuff in your url, but imagine it is just:

```
myserver.com/image.aspx?stuff=1&date=
```

You could then do:

```
img.attr("src", "http://myserver.com/image.aspx?stuff=1&date=" + dateStr);
```

Does this make sense? The code making dateStr could be a bit tighter.