# How to insert today's date into Multiple Image URLs?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a same question but I have multiple image URLs:  [How to insert today's date into a IMAGE URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27772865/how-to-insert-todays-date-into-a-image-url)

I have the image URL as follows:

```
<img src="https://www.example.com/2023/01/08/dl/01/image.jpg" alt="image"><br>
<img src="https://www.example.com/2023/01/08/dl/02/image.jpg" alt="image"><br>
<img src="https://www.example.com/2023/01/08/dl/03/image.jpg" alt="image"><br>
<img src="https://www.example.com/2023/01/08/dl/04/image.jpg" alt="image"><br>
<img src="https://www.example.com/2023/01/08/dl/05/image.jpg" alt="image"><br>
```

How do I insert today's date code on all the IMAGE URLs using javascript.

Comment: can't you use loop? and use the same method of the duplicate question link you provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the shortest way I can think of

`String(i+1).padStart(2,'0')` will create the 01, 02 etc

```js
const yyyymmdd = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0].split('-').join('/'); 
document.getElementById('imgContainer').innerHTML = Array.from({length:5})  // generate an array of 5
  .map((_,i) => `<img src="https://www.example.com/${yyyymmdd}/dl/${String(i+1).padStart(2,'0')}/image.jpg" alt="image" />`).join(`<br/>`)
```

```html
<div id="imgContainer"></div>
```

Change the padStart if you have more than 99 images

Comment: Your answer helped exactly what I wanted. But i need more improvement if i create a form where a user can change the city and date after the user input img src changed accordingly. [detailed questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75047433/how-to-change-img-tag-src-based-drop-down-menu-and-date)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to add a date to each image:

```
const date = new Date();
const dd = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
const mm = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); 
const yyyy = date.getFullYear();

const today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;

const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    
images.forEach(function(img) {
  img.src = img.src.replace(/.jpg/, '-' + today + '.jpg');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here's the code.

```js
const date = new Date();
const year = date.getFullYear();
let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
month < 10 ? month = '0' + month : month;  
let day = date.getDate();
day < 10 ? day = '0' + day : day;  

const fullDate  = `${year}/${month}/${day}`;

let href = 'https://www.example.com/2023/01/08/dl/05/image.jpg';

var links = document.getElementsByClassName("img");

for(let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].setAttribute("src", `https://www.example.com/${fullDate}/dl/05/image.jpg`);
}
```

```html
<!-- add a class to all of the images so you can access them with js -->

<!-- you may delete src attr -->

<img alt="image" class="img" ><br>
<img alt="image" class="img"><br>
<img alt="image" class="img"><br>
<img alt="image" class="img"><br>
<img alt="image" class="img"><br>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make a function to add the date to a single element(from the question you linked). Put the image elements into an array using querySelecterAll().

Then do something like this

```
arrayOfImages.foreach((img) => addDateToImage(img))
```