# How To Change IMG Tag src Based Drop Down Menu and Date?

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose that i have 20 IMG Tags Which Remain Same But I Wanted to add a funcnalty where a user can select the city and date after selecting the city & date all image src changed according to user input.

Here is my img tags looks like:

```
<img src="https://www.example.com/2023/01/08/dl/01/image.jpg" alt="image"><br>
<img src="https://www.example.com/2023/01/08/dl/02/image.jpg" alt="image"><br>
<img src="https://www.example.com/2023/01/08/dl/03/image.jpg" alt="image"><br>
<img src="https://www.example.com/2023/01/08/dl/04/image.jpg" alt="image"><br>
<img src="https://www.example.com/2023/01/08/dl/05/image.jpg" alt="image"><br>
```

I created a form like this:

[Form for user input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLyJV.png)

Here `dl` is the city code.

```
<center><span>-: Select Your City :-</span><br>
<form action="" method="POST">
<select name="city">
<option value="">Select city...</option>
<option value="dl" selected>Delhi</option>
<option value="mb">Mumbai</option>
<option value="bl">Banglore</option>
<option value="hy">Hyderabad</option>
<option value="ch">Chennai</option>
<option value="ch">Kolkata</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<span>Select Date :-</span>
<br>
<input type="date" name="old" value="2023-01-08" min="2015-01-01" max="2023-01-08" required />
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form></center>
```

The default city should be Delhi & Date should be currnt date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change imagesource like you want you'll have to use javascript. and make the date dynamic:

```
const today = new Date();
const year = today.getFullYear();
const month = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
const day = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');


// Get the form elements
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const citySelect = form.querySelector('select[name="city"]');
const dateInput = document.querySelector('input[type="date"]');
dateInput.value = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
dateInput.max = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;


// Add an event listener to the form that will run a function
// when the form is submitted
form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    // Prevent the form from submitting and refreshing the page
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get the selected city and date values
    const city = citySelect.value;
    const date = dateInput.value;

    // Get all the img elements
    const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');

    // Update the src attribute of each img element
    images.forEach((image, index) => {
        const imageNumber = String(index + 1).padStart(2, '0');
        image.src = `https://www.example.com/${date}/${city}/${imageNumber}/image.jpg`;
        image.alt = `image nr:${index+1}of ${city} on ${date}`;
    });
});
```

And the date input should just be changed to this:

```
<input type="date" name="old" min="2015-01-01" required />
```

Not sure what you want to achieve with this code but this does what you requested

Comment: <option value="ch">Chennai</option>
<option value="ch">Kolkata</option> Have the same value, so this would also need to be changed

Comment: Your code works excalty want i want but the date in the url generate 2023-01-08 but I want like this 2023/01/08.

Comment: Use this as image soruce then: **image.src = `https://www.example.com/${date.replace(/-/g, '/')}/${city}/${imageNumber}/image.jpg`;**

Comment: Now the whole funcnalty which I want working perfectly. please help me more about the **input date** field to show the current date when the page load the first time & restrict the user not to select a date more than the current date. Thanks for Your Help :)

Comment: That already gets done with the dateinput.Value and max. Worked when I tested it. Check here https://jsfiddle.net/54evo7p0/

Comment: I removed the value & max filed Because they are static in my code now i want to make it dynamic because current date changed everyday. as you suggest `<input type="date" name="old" min="2015-01-01" required />`

Comment: This is the correct link: https://jsfiddle.net/pverbyx9/

Comment: You saved my life man! one more thing is there any way to not to put all the img tags static make them dynamic like <div id="imgContainer"></div> make a single div and make a loop to 30 src which check status code of the urls and join them. like **document.getElementById('imgContainer').innerHTML = Array.from({length:30})  // generate an array of 30
  .map((_,i) => `<img src="https://www.example.com/${date}/${city}/${imageNumber}/image.jpg" alt="image" />`).join(`<br/>`)**

Comment: You can click [edit], then `[<>]` to make a snippet here instead of in jsfiddle.

Comment: @DhirazSingh Why not try? Also to paste a comment that has a `\`` in it, escape the `\`` using a \

Comment: `document.getElementById('imgContainer').innerHTML = Array.from({length:30}) .map((_,i) => \`<img src="https://www.example.com/${date}/${city}/${String(i+1).padStart(2, '0')}/image.jpg" alt="image${(i+1)}" />\`).join('<br/>');`