# Putting today's date into a URL on a page

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to click on a link running on a page on my local computer (not on a server) that automatically suffixes today's date to the link in question. I've seen another discussion on this site ([How to insert today's date into a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728219/how-to-insert-todays-date-into-a-url)) as to how to put today's date into a URL. However, I can't get any of the code in that stack to work on my page. What exactly do I need to put into the head (all of it, please; assume I know nothing) and how do I format the link so that a link of the form "some.domain.com/?today's_date=" gets today's date added after the = in the form yyyy-mm-dd? Thanks, all.

Comment: you may want to refer to javascript ajax http get method.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){    
var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd
    } 
    if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm
    }

    var today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
    $('a.link').each(function() {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        if (url.indexOf("?") >= 0) {
             $(this).attr("href",url+"&feature_date="+today);  
        } else {
            $(this).attr("href",url+"?feature_date="+today);  
        }
    });       
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<big> <big> <a class="link"  style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: bold;" target="_blank" href="http://www.gocomics.com/">GoComics.com</a> </big> </big>
<a  class="link" style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: bold;" target="_blank" href="http://www.gocomics.com/2cowsandachicken">(Two
Cows and a Chicken)</a><big><big>
  <br  style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: bold;">
  <a  class="link" style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: bold;"
  target="_blank"
  href="http://www.oregonlive.com/comics-kingdom/">Comics Kingdom Favorites</a>
  <br>
 </big></big><a  class="link"
style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: bold;"
target="_blank" href="http://www.oregonlive.com/comics-kingdom/?feature_id=Beetle_Bailey">Beetle
Bailey (Oregon Live)</a><big><big>
  <br
  style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: bold;">
  <a   class="link" style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: bold;"
  target="_blank" href="http://www.dilbert.com/">Dilbert</a>
  <br>
```

Try this one:

Html code:

```
   <HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Your Title Here</TITLE>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY BGCOLOR="FFFFFF">
        <a class="link" target="_blank" href="http://www.gocomics.com/">GoComics.com</a>
        <a class="link" target="_blank" href="http://www.gocomics.com/2cowsandachicken">(Two
        Cows and a Chicken)</a>
        <a class="link" target="_blank" href="http://www.oregonlive.com/comics-kingdom/">Comics Kingdom Favorites</a>
        <a class="link" target="_blank" href="http://www.oregonlive.com/comics-kingdom/?feature_id=Beetle_Bailey">Beetle
        Bailey (Oregon Live)</a>
        <a class="link" target="_blank" href="http://www.dilbert.com/">Dilbert</a>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Css code :

```
.link {
   font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Js code:

```
 $(function(){    
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd
    } 
    if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm
    }

    var today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
    $('a.link').each(function() {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        if (url.indexOf("?") >= 0) {
             $(this).attr("href",url+"&feature_date="+today);  
        } else {
            $(this).attr("href",url+"?feature_date="+today);  
        }
    });       
});
```

Example: [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/4erw6L5z/2/)

Comment: When I click on your example link, the resultant page throws the string "?today_date=2015-05-21" twice, which I'm pretty sure won't do what I want it to. And when I plug your code into my page, the date doesn't insert into the URL. Not sure what's going on. But this seems to be heading in the right direction; it just needs tweaking.

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle. I will check it.

Comment: you included js plugin in your page ?

Comment: I checked my code that is not problem in code. they redirected the website. now i updated the example site name. its now working good.  check this link :  http://jsfiddle.net/uXn2p/140/

Comment: I see where the new link does work to append today's date to the URL. But I don't see a js plugin in your code; to what do you refer? And how do you use jsfiddle? Never used it before.

Comment: In jsfiddle have option to include the js and other plugin.check  the left side under the "Frameworks & Extensions"  text. there i loaded the js plugin. if you still you have doubt means please add your code. i will check it.

Comment: Follow the steps to add your code.  change your code in this link http://jsfiddle.net/uXn2p/140/ and click the update link in top mean. then it you will get new url. then send to me that url. i will check it.

Comment: OK, now I see. Being unfamiliar with jsfiddle, I didn't realize that a plugin was involved. I found code at blog.jquery.com to add the plugin to my page; now that I'm running the plugin, the code does what I wanted it to do. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: OK, spoke too soon. The code now redirects every link to this code; I only needed one link redirected. There's something strange going on when every link on the page gets redirected to the same location, regardless of the fact that the rest of the links are hard-coded.

Comment: Hi, If my code is really useful to you means click the tick icon and like that near to my answer.

Comment: better u copy and paste your code. i will check it.

Comment: Hi, I changed little bit your code and update in this url. check it.  http://jsfiddle.net/4erw6L5z/2/

Comment: I see what you did above with taking out all the inline styles and using a style tag in the head. What I can't figure out is why your code on jsfiddle appends the date as I desire, yet when I copy and paste your code into my file, all I get is the URL at the intended link (the Comics Kingdom Favorites link). I found this in the head of the Result frame:

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

Does that have anything to do with it?

Comment: I think you completely misunderstanding. I removed the inline style because of code clean up. I added the common class for all href( link) and  I added the logic in js only. please check the js code.                                                                          $('a.link').each(function() { var url = $(this).attr('href'); if (url.indexOf("?") >= 0) { $(this).attr("href",url+"&feature_date="+today);  } else { $(this).attr("href",url+"?feature_date="+today);  } });

Comment: To borrow a line from "Dr. Strangelove," still negative function. When I mouse over the Comics Kingdom Favorites link, all I get is the link as defined in the <a> tag. I don't get the date appending to it. Are you running your test code from your computer instead of a server of any kind? That was one of the original stipulations, that this code has to run locally, not on a server.

Comment: RKSMR: Are you there? Still trying to figure out why your code runs on jsfiddle and not on my computer. Hope you see this.

Comment: OK, we still have a problem. I updated the code to call the latest version of the jquery plug-in; now all the links are having the date code appended to them again. In fact, when I roll over your code on jsfiddle, I see all the links are having the date code appended to them. I need to isolate it to that one link.

Comment: @kgm4714 - Please check the browser console. You get any error ? I checked in my local its working good. I updated the code. please check it. Its working good.

Comment: Browser console... Don't see anything in my browser labeled as such. (Using a Chromium-based browser.) Suggestions as to where it might hide? And I've been running the file as is without your latest mod; amazingly (and perhaps I'm showing my ignorance of the process), appending the date code to the rest of the links in the file is not affecting those links; they still do what I want them to do. But the one link to which I wanted to append today's date is functioning as I desired. I'll check out your code (same jsfiddle link, I presume?) and see how it's changed compared to what I'm running. TY

Comment: Sorry. I didn't get you. Add your code in Jsfiddle and list out the what you tried and what you expect.

Comment: For some reason, the code isn't working in jsfiddle at all, much less the way it is on my computer. Is there a more reliable way we can communicate over this code?