# Dynamic Hyperlink in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, href

I need to create a hyperlink that will change each day to incorporate the date from the day previous

**Example**:

***For a download link on May 16th***

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/dir/download-2020-05-15" title="Download Link">Download</a>
```

***For a download link on May 17th***

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/dir/download-2020-05-16" title="Download Link">Download</a>
```

I understand that there would probably be some script that can do this for me, but I cannot find it. Sorry if I am repeating other questions here.

Comment: Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728219/how-to-insert-todays-date-into-a-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PatMcInnes : you can create 3 different elements of a tag like this :

```
var elementCreatedOne = document.getElementById("a1”);

var elementCreatedTwo = document.getElementById("a2”);
var elementCreatedThree = document.getElementById("a3”);

var todaysDate = new Date();
var formattedDate= todaysDate.getFullYear() + '-' + (todaysDate.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + todaysDate.getDate();


elementCreatedOne .setAttribute("href", 
    “Link1” + formattedDate);

elementCreatedTwo .setAttribute("href", 
    “Link2” + formattedDate);

elementCreatedThree .setAttribute("href", 
    “Link3” + formattedDate);
```

HTML :

```
<a href="" id="a1” title="Download Link">Download</a>
<a href="" id="a2” title="Download Link">Download</a>
<a href="" id="a3” title="Download Link">Download</a>
```

Comment: Could you explain this a little clearer @user2945950 - I think that this is what I am after but what I need is one for 3 different links.

AKA:
Link 1: address1/date
Link 2: address2/date
Link 3: address3/date

Comment: I will give this a try and let you know the outcome!

Comment: I didnt run the code, please forgive of missed variable names and syntax.

Comment: Didn't seem to work for me - unless I am being a complete putz and I'm doing it wrong

Answer (score 0):

I'm still kinda new to js but I hope this helps...

```
<!-- The download link in which we shall change its target URL -->
<a id="downloadLink" href="#">Download</a>

<!-- Javascript script changing the link with the id "downloadLink" target URL  -->
<script type="text/javascript">
//The first part of the link without the date
var download = "http://www.example.com/dir/download-";

//Gets the link element in which the target URL will be changed
var link = document.getElementById("downloadLink");

//Gets the current date and formats it as yyyy-mm-dd
var cd = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10); 

//Finally we change the links "href" attribute so it will now include the first part of the download link and date 
link.href = download + cd;
</script>
```